# How do you change the ListTemplateID of an existing SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint

I have several lists in a sitecollection that are currently using ListTemplateID 101 (DocumentLibary).  I want to attach an eventhandler to these lists, but if I attach the event to list 101 all of the document libaries in the sitecollection will get this eventhandler.

I do not want to programatically attach the eventhandler to these lists.

I would like to know, how do you change the ListTemplateID for an existing list?

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lists have already been created, unfortunately you are stuck with programmatically attaching the event handler or using a custom tool to manually attach them.

Once the lists have been created, the ListTemplateID is stored in the database and there is no supported way of changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can do that. It most certainly will be more work than just attaching the event handlers to the existing lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attache event handlers only to certain lists and don't want to do this programatically, you can use the [SharePoint Server 2007 - Custom Site Administration Applications](http://www.codeplex.com/SPSCustomAdmin/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3024) from [Brian Wilson](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-3-register-event-handlers-plus-free-site-settings-manage-event-handlers-add-on.aspx).

It adds a new menu entry to the website settings. There you can select a site, a list or a content type to which you want attache the event handler and you can also define which event should fire the handler.

I hope this will help you solving your problem.